# Configuring MAXITEMSIZE in memcached in gentoo

Tags: memcached, gentoo

Got memcached up and running (emerged `net-misc/memcached`) but on PHP I'm getting

```
Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 35817, udp 0) failed with: SERVER_ERROR object too large for cache
```

I'm thus trying to change the MAXITEMSIZE variable to allow for bigger variables (I am saving a few ones bigger than 1MB)

and tried to edit `/etc/conf.d/memcached` with adding the following (both options just in case):

`MAXITEMSIZE="1234567"
 item_size_max="1234567"`

but to no avail. Even though changing other variables in that file and restarting memcached does show when I do:

```
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 112211
```

This one refuses to be set.

What am I missing?

Is there a documentation on installing a cluster of servers on gentoo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing this option should be with the -I parameter passed to the daemon. So in the same `/etc/conf.d/memcached` I changed

```
# Other Options
MISC_OPTS=""
```

to 128M this way:

```
# Other Options
MISC_OPTS="-I 128M"
```

Of course you can choose your own block size. Now restarting the daemon shows a warning

> /etc/init.d/memcached restart  * Caching service dependencies ...
>   [ ok ]  * Stopping memcached ...
>   [ ok ]  * Starting memcached ... WARNING: Setting item max size above
>   1MB is not recommended!  Raising this limit increases the minimum
>   memory requirements  and will decrease your memory efficiency.